# I am trying to iterate through a Hashmap<LinkedList<String>, int[]>>. Is there a simpler way to do it than what I am doing?

Tags: java, generics

For a project, I have to create a map where the keys are `List`s of `String` and the value is two integers.  So, I made it like this:

```
private Map<LinkedList<String>, int[]> playerProfile;
private List<String> previousChoices;
```

Then later I have to iterate through the map and write all the key-value combinations to a data file.  So I am setting up an iterator like this:

```
    Set<Entry<LinkedList<String>, int[]>> profileSet;
    profileSet = playerProfile.entrySet();

    //iterate through the Set
    List<String> curList; //current list of choices
    int[] curHeadTail; //current list of heads/tails
    Entry<LinkedList<String>, int[]> curEntry;
    Iterator<Entry<LinkedList<String>, int[]>> i =
    profileSet.iterator();
```

What I want to know is: is there a simpler way to do this that takes less lines of code?  And at one point I have triply-nested generics.  Is that too much?

Comment: The only "solution" I've seen to nested generics is to define subclasses that extend generic types, simulating `typedef`. Also, you might want to use `List<String>` instead of `LinkedList<String>` unless you have a good reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use a for-each loop:

```
for(Entry<LinkedList<String>, int[]> curEntry : playerProfile.entrySet()){
    // now you can use curEntry
}
```

And no, nested generics here (and in general) are not a problem.